# Can't use my sprint key and jump at the same time

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, keyboard

I do a lot of sprint jumping in Minecraft because I PVP a ton everyday. Every once in a while, it won't allow me to do both at the same time. I set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to my sprint key so when I want to sprint I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>. If I hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> it won't let me jump. If I double tap <kbd>w</kbd> I can sprint and jump at the same time.

Does anybody know why it does this? It's not something to do with my keyboard because it's just fine. It's done this a couple of times and it's quite annoying.

Comment: "not something to do with my keyboard" - have you actually ruled out the possibility that your keyboard won't register ctrl+space?  Most keyboards do have some key combinations that they won't register together (often w,a,s,d are special: they will always be registered in combination with anything else).

Comment: Lots of applications map "Ctrl+space" to an action. Perhaps something else is intercepting the sequence?

Comment: I know it's not my keyboard because it does it with multiple keyboards.

Comment: @Tinklepop560 I think they meant your operating system or a program is binding ctrl+space. Your keyboard doesn't do anything except send keys to the computer.

Comment: I don't think you need to hold `ctrl` to sprint... It's an on/off toggle button. The fact that you're holding it is likely interfering with your jump input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely to do with the fact that you're holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to run. There are a few issues with this:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> is a [recognised keyboard shortcut](https://www.google.com.au/?gfe_rd=ctrl&ei=i8wLU5rIF6yN8Qfd5oGgAg&gws_rd=cr#q=ctrl%2Bspace) in most systems. Minecraft is not one of them however, so this is likely part of your problem.
- In Minecraft, the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to sprint function is actually an "on/off" switch. Hit it once (while moving) to start sprinting, hit it again to stop sprinting. Holding it is likely screwing with your keyboard input when you attempt to jump.

Answer (score 2):

I had PowerToys quick accent on, where if you had a letter plus space, it would show the possible accents. This might be the problem if you have PowerToys